# An inequality regarding degrees of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero
and let $k \subsetneq K$ be a sub-field of $K$.
Assume that the field extension $K(b_1,b_2)/K(a_1,a_2)$
has a finite degree $m_K$
and the field extension $k(b_1,b_2)/k(a_1,a_2)$
has a finite degree $m_k$.
Also assume that $a_1,a_2$ and $b_1,b_2$ are algebraically independent over $k$.

Is it true that $m_k \geq m_K$? When $m_k = m_K$?

Comment: Assume $a_1 = a_2, b_1 = b_2$. Since $k(b_1)/k(a_1)$ is a finite extension, it means that $k(b_1) = k(a_1)[x]/(f)$ where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of $k(a_1)[x]$. Then say that there is an irreducible polynomial $g \in K(a_1)[x]$ dividing $f$ (in $K(a_1)[x]$) such that $g(b_1) = 0$, so that $K(b_1) = K(a_1)[x]/(g)$, and $[K(b_1) : K(a_1)] = deg(g) \le deg(f) = [k(b_1) : k(a_1)]$

Comment: @user1952009 this violates the OP's condition that $a_1, a_2$ and $b_1, b_2$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: @PavelČoupek it shouldn't be very different when adding other elements ?

Comment: Thanks for both of you for your comments. Is it possible to adjust the explanation of user1952009 to my case?

Comment: @user237522 Notice that in the situation you describe, one does not have even the inclusion $k(a_1, a_2)\subseteq k(b_1, b_2)$ in general. Do you additionally assume that this is the case? If yes, then it should be easy to see that at least $m_k \geq m_K$ always holds.

Comment: @PavelČoupek in the situation he wrote, $k(b_1,b_2)/k(a_1,a_2)$ is a finite extension, so that $k(b_1,b_2) = k(a_1,a_2)(c_1,c_2)$. Then it should be true that $K(b_1,b_2) = K(a_1,a_2)(c_1,c_2)$, and the conclusion is what I wrote applied to $[K(a_1,a_2)(c_1):K(a_1,a_2)] \le[k(a_1,a_2)(c_1):k(a_1,a_2)] $, and $[K(a_1,a_2)(c_1)(c_2):K(a_1,a_2)(c_1)] \le [k(a_1,a_2)(c_1)(c_2):k(a_1,a_2)(c_1)] $

Comment: Yes, I assume that $k(a_1,a_2) \subseteq k(b_1,b_2)$. Truly I am most interested when an equality holds.

Comment: @user237522 when $f$ stays irreducible in $K(a_1,a_2)$

Comment: @user1952009 The problem I see is simply that $k(b_1, b_2)$ does not need to contain $a_1, a_2$: Consider for example $K(a_1, a_2)=\mathbb{C}(x, y)$ (i. e. adjoining indeterminates) and $K(b_1, b_2)=\mathbb{C}(x, \zeta_8 \sqrt{y})$, where $\zeta_8=\sqrt{i}$. Then taking $k=\mathbb{Q},$ it should be easy to see that $k(a_1, a_2) \not \subseteq k(b_1, b_2)$, since $y \notin k(b_1, b_2)$... That being said, I don't disagree with your strategy, it just makes the situation trickier, because the assumptions are stronger.

Comment: @PavelČoupek yes but he assumed it is an extension, so that $k(b_1,b_2) = k(a_1,a_2)(b_1,b_2)$

Comment: Interesting comments! Thank you very much both of you. Please can user1952009 write his answer for $a_1 \neq a_2$, $b_1 \neq b_2$.

Comment: @user1952009 I see, Sorry for the confusion, I for some reason thought that your argument should provide an example where the inequality is strict (i.e. that you are assuming that the minimal polynomials "over $k$" would become reducible "over $K$"); with the inequality $m_k \geq m_K$ I agree, but the fact whether it is always an equality seems trickier to me.

Comment: Do you have other conditions (other than $f$ stays irreducible) that guarantee $m_k = m_K$? (I guess that one can find $a_i,b_i,k,K$ such that $m_k > m_K$).

Comment: Perhaps if we assume that $[K : k] < \infty$, then $m_k = m_K$? But actually I wish to assume that $[K : k] = \infty$ (I do not want to take $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $K=\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Since (by assumption) the base fields are of characteristic zero, each of the two field extensions is separable. Also each of the two extensions is assumed to be finite. Therefore, by the primitive element theorem, $k(a_1,a_2,w)=k(b_1,b_2)$ and $K(a_1,a_2,w)=K(b_1,b_2)$, for some $w \in k(b_1,b_2)$ (same $w$!). Hence the first comment (with the appropriate fields) is valid here